# Aligment of Inputs in Bootstrap in Two Rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to align form as it is on the image:

[image]

and this is the code I have so far:

```
<div class="col-md-6 myForm">               
<form role="form" id="assureForm">
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" name="firstname" class="form-control firstname" placeholder="First Name" required />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" name="lastname" class="form-control lastname" placeholder="Last Name" required />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="email" name="email" class="form-control email" placeholder="Email" required="required" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" name="company" class="form-control company"placeholder="Company" />
</div>
</form>
```

This is obviously not what I want, as they all get aligned in one row. How can I align them in two rows?

Comment: have you tried splitting them in **col-md-3** ?

Comment: No.. you are probably right . Split it inside of a form.I will try now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify device too because col-md-6 is will be 50% on mediam screen size but on mobile devoce it'll be 100%

So use: The Bootstrap grid system has four classes:

- xs (for phones)
- sm (for tablets)
- md (for desktops)
- lg (for larger desktops)

Try this,its working fine:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="myForm">
      <form role="form" id="assureForm" class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="firstname" class="form-control firstname" placeholder="First Name" required />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="lastname" class="form-control lastname" placeholder="Last Name" required />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control email" placeholder="Email" required="required" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="company" class="form-control company" placeholder="Company" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

try below code

```
   <div class="col-sm-6 myForm">
        <form role="form" id="assureForm">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="firstname" class="form-control firstname" placeholder="First Name" required />
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="lastname" class="form-control lastname" placeholder="Last Name" required />
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
                    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control email" placeholder="Email" required="required" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="company" class="form-control company" placeholder="Company" />
                </div>

            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this.

```html
<div class="row">
    <form role="form" id="assureForm">
    <div class="col-md-6 myForm">
      <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" name="firstname" class="form-control firstname" placeholder="First Name" required />
      </div>
      
      <div class="form-group">
<input type="email" name="email" class="form-control email" placeholder="Email" required="required" />
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-md-6 myForm">
      <div class="form-group">
<input type="text" name="lastname" class="form-control lastname" placeholder="Last Name" required />
    </div>
      
      <div class="form-group">
<input type="text" name="company" class="form-control company"placeholder="Company" />
     </div>
      
    </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a `<div class="row">` tag

http://jsbin.com/qinokaniho/1/edit?html,console,output

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it, so just in case someone needs it:

```
<div class="col-md-12 myForm">               
<form role="form" id="assureForm">
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" name="firstname" class="form-control firstname" placeholder="First Name" required />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" name="lastname" class="form-control lastname" placeholder="Last Name" required />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="email" name="email" class="form-control email" placeholder="Email" required="required" />
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" name="company" class="form-control company"placeholder="Company" />
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this i think this should help you out

```html
<div class="col-md-6 myForm">               
<form role="form" id="assureForm">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
<input type="text" name="firstname" class="form-control firstname" placeholder="First Name" required />
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
<input type="text" name="lastname" class="form-control lastname" placeholder="Last Name" required />
</div>
 

</div>
  <div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-6 ">
<input type="text" name="firstname" class="form-control firstname" placeholder="First Name" required />
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
<input type="text" name="lastname" class="form-control lastname" placeholder="Last Name" required />
</div>
 

</div>
</form>
</div>
```